# Are there infinitely many non-negative integers not covered by one of these 7 polynomials?

Tags: number-theory

Consider the following polynomials:

$$
\begin{align}
f_1(n, m) &= 30nm + 23n + 7m + 5   \\
f_2(n, m) &= 30nm + 17n + 13m + 7  \\
f_3(n, m) &= 30nm + 23n + 11m + 8  \\
f_4(n, m) &= 30nm + 11n + 29m + 11 \\
f_5(n, m) &= 30nm + 29n + 17m + 16 \\
f_6(n, m) &= 30nm + 19n + 7m + 4   \\
f_7(n, m) &= 30nm + 31n + 13m + 13 \\
\end{align}
$$

where $n, m \in \mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}$

Let $F = (f_1 \cup f_2\: \cup\: ... \cup \:f_7)$

How can I prove that  $\left\vert{\:\mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}} \setminus F\:}\right\vert = \infty$?

Comment: I suppose by $f_i$ you mean the image set $f_i(\mathbb N\times\mathbb N)$?

Comment: Please, remove all those subscripts from the $m$'s and $n$'s! You only need them for the $f$'s.

Comment: @JackM you're correct. Please excuse the abuse of notation. I generally think of functions as sets.

Comment: @TonyK I see what you mean, I just wanted to make it clear that each of the variables are independent. Originally I wrote these polynomials in the form $z_1 = 30n_1m_1$ ...

Comment: Can you find any integers that do not lie in the image?

Comment: One example is to look at $n=0$ and $m=0$ for each $f$. This yields 4 as the smallest element of $F$. So we know that 1,2, and 3 are not in $F$

Comment: It would be nice to even be able to describe the image set of *one* of these functions.

Comment: Check out Max's answer on mathoverflow. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164792/are-there-infinitely-many-natural-numbers-not-covered-by-one-of-these-7-polynomi/164859?noredirect=1#164859